# There is already an open Data Reader associated with this connection which must be closed first vb.net.vb

Tags: mysql, vb.net, connection, datareader

```vb
Dim Conn As MySqlConnection
Dim Command As MySqlCommand
Dim Reader As MySqlDataReader
Dim server As String = "serverxxxxxxxx.1;user=root;database=xxxxxxxxx"

Public Sub testing()
    Conn = New MySqlConnection
    Conn.ConnectionString = server
    Dim datecompare As String = Date.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    Dim primarykey1 As String = ""
    Dim primarykey2 As String = ""
    Try
        If Not Conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            Conn.Open()
        End If

        Dim Query1 As String
        Query1 = "Select * From `tblborrow` Where `DueDate` = '" & datecompare & "'"
        Command = New MySqlCommand(Query1, Conn)
        Reader = Command.ExecuteReader
        While Reader.Read
            primarykey1 = Reader.GetInt32("BorrowID")

            Try
                If Not Conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                    Conn.Open()
                End If

                Dim query2 As String
                query2 = "Update `tblborrow` Set `Remarks` = '" & "Due Date" & "' Where `BorrowID` = '" & primarykey1 & "'"
                Command = New MySqlCommand(query2, Conn)
                Reader = Command.ExecuteReader
                Reader.Close()
                Conn.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
            'end of duedate
        End While
        Reader.Close()
        Conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

    'for OVER DUE
    Try
        If Not Conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            Conn.Open()
        End If

        Dim Query1 As String
        Query1 = "Select * From `tblborrow` Where `DueDate` < '" & datecompare & "'"
        Command = New MySqlCommand(Query1, Conn)
        Reader = Command.ExecuteReader
        While Reader.Read
            primarykey2 = Reader.GetInt32("BorrowID")

            Try
                If Not Conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                    Conn.Open()
                End If
                Dim query2 As String
                query2 = "Update `tblborrow` Set `Remarks` = '" & "Over Due" & "' Where `BorrowID` = '" & primarykey2 & "'"
                Command = New MySqlCommand(query2, Conn)
                Reader = Command.ExecuteReader
                Reader.Close()
                Conn.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
            'end of Over Due
        End While
        Reader.Close()
        Conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Call testing()
End Sub
```

I created a public sub that will select and update the Remarks in my database based on the `borrowID`(this is auto increment). The save date in `DueDate` and compare i declare with the current time today, but every time i click the button where i saved the code i get this error `There is already an open`DataReader`associated with this connection which must be closed first`
i double checked my code and didn't miss to put `reader.close()` after every `conn.close()` or i don't know maybe i missed.. 
i tried some several changes in my code but still i get the same error.
can some help me and build my code? .. thanks.

Comment: 1) What is the data type of `DueDate` in the database? It *should* be [`DATETIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html). 2) What is the type of `BorrowID` in the database? The code in the question reads it as an *integer* but tries to store it in the *string* variables `primarykey1` and `primarykey2`.

Comment: I notice that the code uses `Date.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")`. [`Today`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.today?view=netframework-4.8) has the time part set to 00:00:00 - is that how you want it?

Comment: It will need a second connection for the query that's inside the other query. Also, you can use [`ExecuteNonQuery`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommand_ExecuteNonQuery.htm) for the UPDATE query.

Comment: What is the datatype in your MySql database for the DueDate field? If it is not type Date or DataTime then you need to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use different variable for the readers, maybe `Reader1` and `Reader2`.
It's probably because you used the same reader to execute different query hence the already open datareader error.

You try to open the same book which is already open. At least make it a different book.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to open 2 readers on a single connection. See the double headed arrows.

```vb
Reader = Command.ExecuteReader'<<----
        While Reader.Read
            primarykey1 = Reader.GetInt32("BorrowID")

            Try
                If Not Conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                    Conn.Open()
                End If

                Dim query2 As String
                query2 = "Update `tblborrow` Set `Remarks` = '" & "Due Date" & "' Where `BorrowID` = '" & primarykey1 & "'"
                Command = New MySqlCommand(query2, Conn)
                Reader = Command.ExecuteReader '<<----
```

If you break your code into logical units with only a single thing happening in each method it is a bit easier to see where things go wrong.

Keeping your database objects local to the methods where they are used allows you to be sure they are closed and disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks handle this for you even if there is an error.

Notice, in the 2 Update methods, the parameters are added outside the `For` loop and only the value that changes is set inside the loop.

```
Dim ConString As String = "serverxxxxxxxx.1;user=root;database=xxxxxxxxx"

Public Sub GetPKs()
    Dim pkList As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim DueDate As String = Date.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    Using Conn As New MySqlConnection(ConString),
            cmd As New MySqlCommand("Select BorrowID From tblborrow Where DueDate = @DueDate")
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DueDate", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = DueDate
        Conn.Open()
        Using reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            While reader.Read
                pkList.Add(reader.GetInt32("BorrowID"))
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
    UpdateRemarks(pkList, DueDate)
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateRemarks(pks As List(Of Integer), DueDate As String)
    Using con As New MySqlConnection(ConString),
            cmd As New MySqlCommand("Update tblborrow Set Remarks = @DueDate Where BorrowID = @PK", con)
        With cmd.Parameters
            .Add("@DueDate", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = DueDate
            .Add("@PK", MySqlDbType.Int32)
        End With
        con.Open()
        For Each i In pks
            cmd.Parameters("@PK").Value = i
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub GetOverduePKs()
    Dim pkList As New List(Of Integer)
    Using cn As New MySqlConnection(ConString),
            cmd As New MySqlCommand("Select BorrowID From tblborrow Where DueDate < @DueDate")
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DueDate", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = Date.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
        cn.Open()
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            While reader.Read
                pkList.Add(reader.GetInt32("BorrowID"))
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
    UpdateOverdueRemarks(pkList)
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateOverdueRemarks(pks As List(Of Integer))
    Using cn As New MySqlConnection(ConString),
            cmd As New MySqlCommand("Update tblborrow Set Remarks = 'Over Due' Where BorrowID = @PK")
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PK", MySqlDbType.Int32)
        cn.Open()
        For Each i In pks
            cmd.Parameters("@PK").Value = i
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    GetPKs()
    GetOverduePKs()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

use 2 connections CONN and CONN2, with the same parameters, use CONN to open the QUERY1 reader. While reading, use CONN2 to create the 2nd query. Note that this works for MySQL. **MS-Access** can handle multiple commands in one connection, **MySql** cannot and needs separate connections. **Sqlite** cannot handle 2 simultanuos connections. there you have to use in incore temporary array or list. From a working program:

```
   Dim DbConn As New MySqlConnection(SqlProv)
   Dim DbConn2 As New MySqlConnection(SqlProv)
```

-

```
    Dim SQLsfSelect As String = "SELECT CollSeq FROM ToBeIndexed WHERE CollCode = @CollCode"
    Dim DRsfSelect As MySqlDataReader = Nothing
    Dim DCsfSelect As MySqlCommand
    Dim sfSelP1 As New MySqlParameter("@CollCode", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 4)
    DCsfSelect = New MySqlCommand(SQLsfSelect, DbConn)
```

-

```
    Dim SQLasSelect As String = "SELECT DISTINCT CollSeq FROM Data WHERE CollCode = @CollCode ORDER BY CollSeq"
    Dim DRasSelect As MySqlDataReader = Nothing
    Dim DCasSelect As MySqlCommand
    Dim asSelP1 As New MySqlParameter("@CollCode", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 4)
    DCasSelect = New MySqlCommand(SQLasSelect, DbConn2)
```

-

```
DbConn.Open()
        sfSelP1.Value = CurCollCode
        CollSeqToIdxC.Clear()
        Try
            DRsfSelect = DCsfSelect.ExecuteReader()
            Do While (DRsfSelect.Read())
                CollSeq = GetDbIntegerValue(DRsfSelect, 0)
                DbConn2.Open()
                asSelP1.Value = CurCollCode
                Try
                    DRasSelect = DCasSelect.ExecuteReader()
                    Do While (DRasSelect.Read())
                        CollSeq = GetDbIntegerValue(DRasSelect, 0)
                        CollSeqToIdxC.Add(CollSeq, CStr(CollSeq))
                    Loop
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.ToString(), , SysMsg1p(402, CurCollCode))
                Finally
                    If Not (DRasSelect Is Nothing) Then
                         DRasSelect.Close()
                    End If
                End Try
                DbConn2.Close()
            Loop
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString(), , SysMsg1p(403, CurCollCode))
        Finally
            If Not (DRsfSelect Is Nothing) Then
                DRsfSelect.Close()
            End If
        End Try
        DbConn.Close()
```